# How to Transform 1 to Many relationship between two Class

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have two class which has 1 to many relationship. Need to Transform object of `DepartmentEmployees` to `EmployeeDepartments`.

```
//Employee to Department (1-n) relation
public class DepartmentEmployeesEntity
{
    public DepartmentEntity Department { get; set; }

    public List<EmployeeEntity> Employees { get; set; }

}

//Employee to Department (1-n) relation
public class EmployeeDepartmentsEntity
{
    public EmployeeEntity Employee { get; set; }

    public List<DepartmentEntity> Departments { get; set; }   
}

public class University
{
    public List<DepartmentEmployeesEntity> DepartmentEmployees { get; set; }

    public List<EmployeeDepartmentsEntity> EmployeeDepartments { get; set; }   
}
```

The Data for `DepartmentEmployees` is stored in database in a json format. How do I transform the `DepartmentEmployees` object to `EmployeeDepartments` object.

Comment: Just do it as post processing.  Would not be efficient to serialise both

Comment: _Just do it as post processing_.  _"efficient way"_ is sadly _subject to opinion_ and off-topic for SO

Comment: @MickyD I needed the answer and I got it from Georg. I needed  to know how to post process it first and then if there were multiple answers i needed to the efficient one. That;s the only reason I added in an efficient way.  If you still feel the question has to be closed no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary to speed up the lookup of the employees while you are transforming the data.

```
var entitiesByEmployee = new Dictionary<Employee, EmployeeDepartmentsEntity>();
```

Then loop over your data and create or update the EmployeeDepartmentsEntity entries in the dictionary.

```
var allDepartmentEmployeesEntities = dbContext.DepartmentEmployeesEntity.ToArray();
foreach (var departmentEmployee in allDepartmentEmployeesEntities) {
   foreach(var employee in departmentEmployee.Employees) {
      if (entitiesByEmployee.ContainsKey(employee)) {
          // this employee already showed up in another department, update his entry
          entitiesByEmployee[employee].Departments.Add(departmentEmployee.Department)
      }
      else {
          // this employee has not been processed yet, create new entry
          var newEntry = new EmployeeDepartmentsEntity {
              Employee = employee,
              Departments = new List<DepartmentEntity> {departmentEmployee.Department}
          };
          entitiesByEmployee.Add(employee, newEntry);
      }
   }
}
```

Finally, your result are all the values in the dictionary:

```
List<EmployeeDepartmentsEntity> employeeDepartments = entitiesByEmployee.Values.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Any solution would require you to flatten the initial list (dep->employees) and then group by employees (emp->departments).

Using linq you can do the two steps as:

```
List<DepartmentEmployeesEntity> dep = new List<DepartmentEmployeesEntity>();
dep = PopulateData();
var step1 = dep.SelectMany(d => d.Employees, (d, e) => new { d.Department, employee = e});
List<EmployeeDepartmentsEntity> empDepList = step1.GroupBy(e => e.employee).Select(g => new EmployeeDepartmentsEntity () { Employee = g.Key, Departments = g.Select(x => x.Department).ToList() }).ToList();
```

I had changed the definition of the entity to the following, i.e. am using `string` type, since you are using a custom type, please ensure that you override  `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods for your classes

```
public class DepartmentEmployeesEntity
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public List<string> Employees { get; set; }
}
```